# Google DFP errors using DFP supplied tags

Tags: google-ads-api, adsense, google-dfp

I've added tags provided by DFP today and yet I'm getting the following error on all the tags.

`getName on googletag.Slot is deprecated and will be removed. Use getAdUnitPath instead.`

I've searched all over for what this means, but can't find an answer anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out...it was caused by the Google Publisher Toolbar extension for chrome. The version I have has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use this one, and it is working.

```
googletag.pubads().getSlots()[0].getAdUnitPath()
```

you could use forloop if you want to iterate on ad-Slots.
i tried to see if getAdUnitPath is a method available in pubads, but could not find anything...
the only article on google i saw about this was:
https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.Slot_getAdUnitPath